# Restrict the Full swipe to dismiss on a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, swipe-gesture

I have several cards inside a recycler view and i have implemented romannurik's swipeToDismiss library which helps to fully swipe and dismiss an Item.
However, i want to try restricting the swipe to say 1/4th of the item width and display a view in the new space which i have after the drag.
Is there any libraries which will do this for me? Or can it be done without a library?

Comment: visit this https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo...may help you